# WPF sorting DataGrid with reset

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting

I have custom sort for my DataGrid

```
if (sortPropertyName == "Ip")
{   
     IComparer comparer = null;                    
     e.Handled = true;
     ListSortDirection direction = (e.Column.SortDirection != ListSortDirection.Ascending) ? ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;         
     e.Column.SortDirection = direction;         
     ListCollectionView lcv = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid.ItemsSource);                     
     comparer = new SortIPAddress(direction);                   
     lcv.CustomSort = comparer;
}
```

It works well. And I have method reset sort for other column

```
if (e.Column.SortDirection.HasValue && e.Column.SortDirection.Value == ListSortDirection.Descending)
{                    
    int index = Helpers.FindSortDescription(dataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions, sortPropertyName);
    if (index != -1)
     {
         e.Column.SortDirection = null;
         // remove the sort description
         dataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.RemoveAt(index);
         dataGrid.Items.Refresh();

         if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) != ModifierKeys.Shift)
         {
           // clear any other sort descriptions for the multisorting case
           dataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
           dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
         }

         // stop the default sort
         e.Handled = true;
     }
}
```

How Can I do reset like in column Ip?

I did:

```
if (e.Column.SortDirection.HasValue && e.Column.SortDirection.Value == ListSortDirection.Descending)
{
  e.Column.SortDirection = null;
}
else
{
  ListSortDirection direction = (e.Column.SortDirection != ListSortDirection.Ascending) ? ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;                        
  e.Column.SortDirection = direction;
  comparer = new SortIPAddress(direction);
}                    
ListCollectionView lcv = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid.ItemsSource);                   
lcv.CustomSort = comparer;
```

Sorting Ip resets now. But double sorting with `shift` is incorrect. How to fix?

Comment: I imagine that if you don't specify a new sortdescription for the original state, it doesn't know how to sort itself/won't sort because you didn't ask it to. Have you tried rebinding the grid? Eg. dataGrid.ItemsSource = null, then set it to your itemssource again.

Comment: If I click third time sort not reset in column IP, column IP sorts again

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the sorting of a column by setting the `SortDirection` property to `null`:

```
e.Column.SortDirection = null;
```

If you want to remove your custom sorting, you could set the `CustomSort` property to `null`:

```
ListCollectionView lcv = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dg.ItemsSource);
lcv.CustomSort = null;
```

Comment: I added code in my question. Please, see. Sorting Ip resets now. But double sorting with `shift` is incorrect. How to fix?

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Don't edit the original question. Your original question was about how to reset the custom sorting.  It's unclear what do you expect to happen when you press Shift.